# How does EE delete entries?

Tags: expressionengine

I'm trying to figure out how ExpressionEngine deletes entries.

I've written an log-like extension that tracks when an entry is created.  When I delete an entry through EE's edit section, the entry is also removed from the separate table I created for my extension.

How does EE know to delete the row from my table when the entry is removed?  One of the columns in my table is `entry_id`.  It would seem like EE automatically checks all tables for a entry_id column and if the value matches the value being deleted, the row is removed.  Can anyone confirm this?

It would explain why I didn't have to make a function that hooks into `delete_entries_loop` to achieve this functionality.

Comment: That's a weird one for sure. Have you tried renaming the `entry_id` column to something else temporarily to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd. That behavior would be insane if it was indeed the case!

Looking at the `delete_entry()` method of the Channel Entries API, the deletions are very specifically limited to:

- channel_titles
- channel_data
- category_posts
- relationships
- comments
- comment_subscriptions
- channel_entries_autosave
- entry_versioning

The Channel Fields API is also called, to let fieldtypes delete what they need to from their own database tables based on the entry being deleted, but only if they contain a `delete()` method.

I'd suggest turning on the output profiler, then running the deletion routine to see what queries are being run.